# What are the performance adjustments for a Beechcraft B1900D on a wet runway?

Tags: aircraft-performance, runway-contamination, beechcraft-1900

I am doing runway analysis for B1900D and AFM Section 5, does not provide correction to V1 or the takeoff weight for takeoff on a wet runway.

Appreciate if someone can provide information regarding such correction or the method.

Answer (score 3):

According to the **Transportation Safety Board of Canada** when they conducted an investigation into [a Beechcraft 1900D overrunning a runway](http://www.bst-tsb.gc.ca/eng/rapports-reports/aviation/1997/a97c0229/a97c0229.pdf) in 1997, they found out that the AFM does not include that information you request, nor was it available to the pilots.

> The snow-covered, slippery condition of the occurrence runway differed from the bare,
>   dry surfaces on which the AFM data is based.

and

> There were no performance data available to the pilots to determine the aircraft's
>   accelerate-stop distance under snowy and slippery runway conditions.

and

> The James Brake Index (JBI) published in the Canada Flight Supplement contains a table which may be used to
>   adjust calculated landing distances to compensate for slippery braking conditions. JBI correction factors for
>   compacted snow or snow-covered runways range from 80% to 250% higher than hard dry surfaces. Transport
>   Canada did not require the manufacturer to provide data on the effects of soft or wet runways, slippery
>   runways, or runways containing loose snow on the aircraft's accelerate-stop distances or take-off distances.

How can the aircraft be approved? They say:

> The manufacturer was, as a condition of the aircraft type approval,
>   required to determine and supply certain aircraft performance data including the balanced field lengths at
>   various take-off weights, temperatures, and altitudes.

I.e., V1 corrections for non-dry runways were (are) not a requirement for the 1900D.

If the AFM you have is current, then it hasn't changed since. If not, then it *may be* present in the latest AFM. (But I wouldn't count on it, so verify before placing a purchase order.)

You may also look into the aforementioned *James Brake Index.*

Comment: I have the current AFM and the  wet runway performance data is not   available. I will look up about JBI and see how it can be adopted for Takeoff performance.